# Send Mouse position over Bluetooth-java

Tags: java, android, serialization, bluetooth

I found the following code, it is to detect the position of the mouse with dummy frame. It shows the position of the mouse outside the program. I mean on the desktop. 
I need to send the position information over Bluetooth to android application. How can I write the code for the client side (desktop)?

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 * This class checks the position every #DELAY milliseconds and 
  * informs all registered MouseMotionListeners about position updates.
 */
public class MouseObserver {
/* the resolution of the mouse motion */
private static final int DELAY = 10;

private Component component;
private Timer timer;
private Set<MouseMotionListener> mouseMotionListeners;

protected MouseObserver(Component component) {
    if (component == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null component not allowed.");
    }

    this.component = component;

    /* poll mouse coordinates at the given rate */
    timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
            private Point lastPoint = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();

            /* called every DELAY milliseconds to fetch the
             * current mouse coordinates */
            public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();

                if (!point.equals(lastPoint)) {
                    fireMouseMotionEvent(point);
                }

                lastPoint = point;
            }
        });
    mouseMotionListeners = new HashSet<MouseMotionListener>();
}

public Component getComponent() {
    return component;
}

public void start() {
    timer.start();
}

public void stop() {
    timer.stop();
}

public void addMouseMotionListener(MouseMotionListener listener) {
    synchronized (mouseMotionListeners) {
        mouseMotionListeners.add(listener);
    }
}

public void removeMouseMotionListener(MouseMotionListener listener) {
    synchronized (mouseMotionListeners) {
        mouseMotionListeners.remove(listener);
    }
}

protected void fireMouseMotionEvent(Point point) {
    synchronized (mouseMotionListeners) {
        for (final MouseMotionListener listener : mouseMotionListeners) {
            final MouseEvent event =
                new MouseEvent(component, MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                               0, point.x, point.y, 0, false);

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        listener.mouseMoved(event);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}

/* Testing the ovserver */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame main = new JFrame("dummy...");
    main.setSize(100,100);
    main.setVisible(true);

    MouseObserver mo = new MouseObserver(main);
    mo.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("mouse moved: " + e.getPoint());
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("mouse dragged: " + e.getPoint());
            }
        });

    mo.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your starting point for Bluetooth in java is [Bluecove.org](http://www.bluecove.org/). 
Here some sample code to start with.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;

import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.UUID;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnectionNotifier;

public class Desktop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bluetooth bluetooth = new Bluetooth();
        bluetooth.listen();
    }
}

class Bluetooth implements Runnable {
    // the uid of the service, it has to be unique
    final UUID uuid = new UUID("22022c0c68af4cbc8dbf0bbaf2aa222a", false);
    // the name of the service
    final String name = "Echo Server";
    // the service url
    final String url = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid + ";name=" + name + ";authenticate=false;encrypt=false;";

    DataOutputStream dout;
    DataInputStream din;
    LocalDevice local = null;
    StreamConnectionNotifier server = null;

    StreamConnection conn = null;
    // if client is ready to receive data
    boolean remoteReady = true;

    public Bluetooth() {
        try {
            local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
            local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);
            server = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void listen() {
        try {
            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            boolean listening = true;
            boolean firstTime = true;
            String cmd = "";
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (listening) {
                        conn = server.acceptAndOpen();
                        // Client Connected waiting for incoming data
                        din = new DataInputStream(conn.openInputStream());
                        dout = new DataOutputStream(conn.openOutputStream());
                        listening = false;
                        firstTime = false;
                    } else {
                        cmd = din.readUTF();
                        if (cmd.equals("ACK"))
                            remoteReady = true;
                        /**
                         * here you can send the cursor position
                         */

                        String position = "{x:1,y:1}";
                        sendDataIfReady(position.getBytes());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    close();
                    if (firstTime) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    }
                    listening = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendData(String data) {
        try {
            dout.writeUTF(data);
            dout.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean sendDataIfReady(String data) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            if (remoteReady) {
                remoteReady = false;
                dout.writeUTF(data);
                dout.flush();
                result = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void sendData(byte[] data) {
        try {
            dout.write(data, 0, data.length);
            dout.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean sendDataIfReady(byte[] data) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            if (remoteReady) {
                remoteReady = false;
                dout.write(data, 0, data.length);
                dout.flush();
                result = true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```